# Sencha touch List clean data

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have following code.

```
var list = this.getNavigation();
if (list.itemsCount > 0) {
   list.removeAll(true, true);
}
list.setData(filtered);
```

List = xtype: list.
So idea is next i have menu and some times i need to rebuild it. as you see i am not using store because i need to filter array and set it. 
When i call removeAll i got error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getScroller' of undefined
```

And i cant find method to cleanup it...

Comment: Do you have a store behind the list?

Comment: No i just set array using setData

Comment: Why don't you filter data in a store?

Comment: I thought since list has method set it would be easy but now i see that i should use store for it

Comment: Thanks everyone, yes using store it works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote my menu to use store and instead of setData on list i am setting data on store and it works as expected

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be calling removeAll with destroy set to `false` like so:

```
var list = this.getNavigation();
if (list.itemsCount > 0) { list.removeAll(false); }
list.setData(filtered);
```

The list DOM items get deleted anyways by some sort of auto-cleanup.